# Need inputs for Food data set to predict consumer ordering behaviour

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, statistics

I am looking for food order data set that shows the consumer list and type of food they order regularly. Like :
customer_number, gender, day, time, choice_of_food, food_category, quantity(grams), Calories, Carbs, Fat, protein

Purpose is to predict the choice_of_food any customer can make on a given day.
Please help with your valuable comments from where I can find similar data-set.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe you should try another StackExchange that is entirely on Open Data https://opendata.stackexchange.com/